# Android : GridView different ColumnNum for each row

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-custom-view

**PROBLEM**

I have search about this (**GridView different ColumnNum for each row**) but it seem impossible.

However, I may not know something or misunderstanding.

So, Can I create GirdView to have a result like below sample ??

If not, are there any approach to achieve this??

**NOTE::**

I understand how to create custom GridView and different style of Gridview Layout in one GridView

```
|-----------------|  |-----------------|
|                 |  |                 |
|                 |  |                 |
|-----------------|  |-----------------|

|----------|  |----------|  |----------|
|          |  |          |  |          |
|          |  |          |  |          |
|----------|  |----------|  |----------|

|-----------------|  |-----------------|
|                 |  |                 |
|                 |  |                 |
|-----------------|  |-----------------|
```

Comment: so you need this because you have an adapter (like ArrayAdapter) as source of your data, right?

Comment: yep! I have ArrayAdapter

Comment: then listview with different row types might by an answer. please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a ListView.

So that your listview doesn't have one type of view for it's row but two:

- first one is two-elements-per-row type
- second one is three-elements-per-row

Your adapter has to override this method:

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29)

and of course you have to adjust your ArrayAdapter type so that it's not "flat", ie. ArrayAdapter but something a bit more complex, ie:

```
class MyTypeWrapper {
     class List<MyType> objects;
}
```

so that in both getItemViewType you can do something like this:

```
...
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    MyTypeWrapper m = getItem(position)
    if (m.objects.size() == 2) {
        return TWO_ITEMS_PER_ROW_VIEW_TYPE;
    } else {
        return THREE_ITEMS_PER_ROW_VIEW_TYPE;
    }
}
...
```

and then later in getView() you have different layouts for different rows.

I bet it sounds a bit difficult but it's not!
Just google for "android listview different row types"